# Небольшой вопрос про javafx

Tags: java, javafx, график

В **javafx**, а конкретнее в **linechart** есть 2 шкалы (x и y). Я хочу в названиях шкал вставить сложную формулу (вместо фи(т) добавить в него еще, например, степень). Подскажите возможно ли это?
Вот собственно как выглядит шкала y:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вариант с использованием `jlatexmath` добавлен в Ваш предыдущий вопрос [Как изменить стандартную шкалу в LineChart JAVAFX?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841782/291565)

Answer (score 1):

В чистом виде `JavaFX` не поддерживает подобного форматирования (исключение  `WebView`, при отображении текста в `HTML` формате).

Но имеется ограниченный набор стандартных символов в `unicode`, которые могут вам помочь. См. [таблицу символов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts#Superscripts_and_subscripts_block)

Пример использования:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String string = "x\u00B2";

        Text text = new Text(string);
        Label label = new Label(string);

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.addRow(0, new Text("Text:"), text);
        gridPane.addRow(1, new Text("Label: "), label);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```